# Strange behavior of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a very weird trouble with PostgreSQL 10: I have a fairly large database that serves a lot of SELECT and UPDATE queries per second. Until recently everything was fine, but I noticed that tens and hundreds of queries (UPDATEs) of the same type accumulate in the
queue:

[image]

As it looks like in the frame of processes count (normal behavior is 20-30 concurrent sessions, but not 300-400):

[image]

With all this, the server does not experience any significant load or even overload:

[image]

My server is:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 4.15.0-112-generic
CPU: Intel Xeon Silver 4214 (48 Cores) @ 2.201GHz
Memory: 96Gb
SSD SAMSUNG MZQLB960HAJR-00007 894.3Gb x 2
```

What could be the problem? How can I optimize this? I'll be grateful for any ideas. Thank you!

**Update:** Also I've noticed that I have a few `VACUUM(ANALYZE, VERBOSE) one_large_table` in the processes list. I think, it's something wrong if I have 10 and more such VACUUMs?

Comment: What is the client making these requests?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That's high loaded web application.

Comment: So maybe a robot or scriptkiddie is having fun with the website?

Comment: Look in the other columns of pg_stat_activity.

Comment: The query you list shows not only the active backends, so the result doesn't tell us anything. Look for locks - locked queries are active, but consume no CPU.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, nope, actually, the system works as it should, except of lots UPDATEs in the queue.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe all the hanging UPDATEs have `wait_event_type=Lock` and `wait_event=transactionid`. In addition, after restart Postgres I observe correct operation for a couple of hours - and after that queries start to accumulate again

Comment: Then run `SELECT pg_blocking_pids(36059);` for a hanging backend PID and see in `pg_stat_activity` what sessions are blocking you. Then change your application so that it closes those transactions rather than keeping them open indefinitely long.

Comment: Also I've noticed that I have a few `VACUUM(ANALYZE, VERBOSE) one_large_table` in the processes list. I think, it's something wrong if I have 10 and more such VACUUMs?